# Fetch Min, Max and current price

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle database table with below data.

```
Stock_name Current_Price Created_Date
---------- ------------- ------------
ABC        200        29-JAN-2018
ABC        195        28-JAN-2018
ABC        210        27-JAN-2018
ABC        175        26-JAN-2018
DEF        60         29-JAN-2018
DEF        10         28-JAN-2018
DEF        70         27-JAN-2018
DEF        80         26-JAN-2018
```

From this table i want to fetch, stock name, min price, max price and current price value, here current price means which is latest price from the table.

This is what I have tried

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT STOCK_NAME, MIN_PRICE, MAX_PRICE, (100 - ((MIN_PRICE/MAX_PRICE) *100)) AS PERCENTAGE_CHANGE FROM (SELECT STOCK_NAME, 
  MIN(CURRENT_PRICE) AS MIN_PRICE, MAX(CURRENT_PRICE) AS MAX_PRICE FROM 
  MKT_GOOD_STOCKS WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-3) AND 
  SYSDATE GROUP BY STOCK_NAME ORDER BY STOCK_NAME)) ORDER BY 
  PERCENTAGE_CHANGE DESC;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include some of your code if you want help with it

Comment: **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Your query does not match your requirement. You don't mention anything about "last three months" or "price change percentage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
select distinct Stock_name,
   min(Current_Price) over (partition by Stock_name),
   max(Current_Price) over (partition by Stock_name),
   LAST_VALUE(Current_Price) over (partition by Stock_name order by Created_Date)
from your_table;
```

Another approach is this:

```
select Stock_name.
   min(Current_Price),
   max(Current_Price),
   MAX(Current_Price) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Created_Date)
from your_table
group by Stock_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation values per `STOCK_NAME`, so you'll group by this column and use appropriate aggregation functions on the other values:

```
select
  stock_name,
  min(current_price) as min_price, 
  max(current_price) as max_price,
  max(current_price) keep (dense_rank last order by created_date) as last_price,
  100 - (min(current_price) / max(current_price) * 100) as percentage_change 
from mkt_good_stocks
group by stock_name
order by percentage_change desc;
```